# Can one massacre lives?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

"Most were convinced that those responsible were of their own, silently waiting for another chance to massacre innocent lives."

Would you say that the above example is acceptable or unacceptable with regard to the verb "massacre" in conjunction with the noun "lives"?

Comment: Massacre def. involves indisriminate killing. One does *not* kill lives, innocent or otherwise; better to massacre innocents.

Comment: So you're advocating the massacre of innocents?

Comment: Exactly. Anything more is redundant.

Comment: No, I understand. I was being facetious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough, one of the lesser meaning of the word massacre does not imply loss of live: " an act of complete destruction i.e.the author's massacre of traditional federalist presuppositions " (Webster). In this sense you could say "a massacre of innocent lives" in the context of , for example, a serial children rapist, a crooked financial advisor destroying lives in stealing life savings of middle aged persons etc. I agree that it's slightly stretched (or poetic).